# C# Continuously / uninterrupted reading data (from third party SDK)

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Intro:**
I am developing software that uses motion trackers to analyse human motor systems. Currently I am implementing hardware from xsens and using their SDK to receive data from their wireless sensors.
The SDK offers a COM interface with a "getData" method which you call to receive the currently available xyz axis data (simplified). If you do not call getData, you skip that "beat" so you will be missing data, there is no caching in their hardware/SDK.

**Problem:**
My problem is that I need to get data at a rate of at least 75Hz, preferably a bit more, but 75 would be acceptable, but I am currently quickly dropping to just 20 signals per second...
If I remove the processing bit (see the sample below) I get perfect sample rates, so I think either the dequeue is causing the enqueue to pause. Or the "heavy" CPU load is causing all threads to wait. I have no idea how to figure out what is actually causing it, the profiler (EQATEC) just shows my "GetData" method is taking longer after a while.

**Question:**
What is the best technique to use to accomplish this? Why would my "reading" thread be interrupted/blocked? There must be more cases where people need to read from something without being interrupted, but I have been Googleing for 2 weeks now and apparently I can't find the correct words.

Please advise.

Thanks

Simplified code sample, version 4, using a MultiMedia timer (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework) and a BackgroundWorker

```
public class Sample
{
  private MultiMediaTimer _backgroundGetData;
  private bool _backgroundGettingData;
  private BackgroundWorker _backgroundProcessData;
  private ConcurrentQueue<double> _acceleration = new ConcurrentQueue<double>();

  private void StartProcess()
  {
    if (_backgroundGetData == null)
    {
      _backgroundGetData = new MultiMediaTimer {Period = 10, Resolution = 1, Mode = TimerMode.Periodic, SynchronizingObject = this};
      _backgroundGetData.Tick += BackgroundGetDataOnTick;
    }

    _backgroundProcessData = new BackgroundWorker {WorkerReportsProgress = false, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true};
    _backgroundProcessData.DoWork += BackgroundProcessDataOnDoWork;

    _backgroundGetData.Start();
  }

  private void BackgroundProcessDataOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
  {
    double value;
    if (!_acceleration.TryDequeue(out value)) value = 0;

    //Do a lot of work with the values collected so far,
    //this will take some time and I suspect it's the cause of the delays?
  }

  private void BackgroundGetDataOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    if (_backgroundGettingData) return;
    _backgroundGettingData = true;

    //123 represents a value I am reading from the sensors using the SDK
    double value = 123;
    if (value == -1)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(5);
      continue;
    }
    _acceleration.Enqueue(value);
    if (_acceleration.Count < 5) continue;

    if (!_backgroundProcessData.IsBusy)
    {
      _backgroundProcessData.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    _backgroundGettingData = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your simplified example has lots of busy waits which will kill performance. You don't have that in the real code do you?

Comment: I also tried timers but they basically had the same problems. So I moved to thread hoping they would offer more possibilities. This is my real code, only the actual getdata and process calls have been simplified.

Comment: Like @MatthewWatson says, why the Sleep() calls?  Presumably, the SDK call blocks until data is available.  Likewise - the queue, why polling?

Comment: The while loop for processing was indeed useless, updated the example to use a thread + backgroundworker setup. But it all makes no difference, the problem is still there. After 2-3 seconds "something" starts blocking up and I no longer get enough samples.

Comment: FYI The problem also occurs when I use 2-3 timer systems (1 queueing, 1 dequeuing and 1 processing). After some time the timer event which does the reading starts to take longer.

Comment: Aarrghh!  Timers!  Look at BlockingCollection.

Comment: Updated the example to use the multimedia timer by Leslie Sanford and now I can get to the desired 100Hz. Final question, would this then be the best method because it works or are there better ways?

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing the problem here

```
 _backgroundProcessDataThread.Start();
 while (!_backgroundProcessDataThread.IsAlive){}

_backgroundGetDataThread.Start();
while (!_backgroundGetDataThread.IsAlive) {}
```

Well, you can see here that you are having infinite loop here and the second thread starts only after first has finished its work. i.e. first thread is done. This is in no way an ideal model.

Sorry, I recognized the issue later.

The problem is, _backgroundGetDataThread will start only after _backgroundProcessDataThread has done its work.

Comment: 1. I already have separate threads for the reading and the processing? 2. Initially I had backgroundworkers, but they seemed to be worse at best and I found posts claiming threads where "better" for tasks that run for the entire length of the app

Comment: Background workers use threads too, so there's no difference in that regard.

Comment: I do not see any reason for this code -  _backgroundProcessDataThread.Start();
    while (!_backgroundProcessDataThread.IsAlive){}

    _backgroundGetDataThread.Start();
    while (!_backgroundGetDataThread.IsAlive) {}

Comment: If you do not want this process to be asynchronous, why you are using threads ?

Comment: It has to be asynchronous, I am using 2 threads. 1 reading as much and as uninterrupted as possible. And 1 processing whatever has been put on the queue.

Comment: @Matthew - There is no performance improvement with using background worker, I recommend it for convenient coding.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I removed the while loops as they are useless. But they don't make a difference, it was a while (!isalive) to wait for the thread to start. It does not help with the issue. Whether I use threads/backgroundworkers/timers the problem remains the same.

Comment: It seems like context switching among threads is taking time. You can use task parallel library to optimize the context switching.

Comment: Step 1 - get rid of the unnecessary polling and Sleep() loops.